# Unity Buttons Player

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a scene in Unity where firstly I made the movements of the animator through buttons, linking the animations like walking and raising hand to the button up/down/left/right and for the raising hand the space one. It went ok, then I installed the XR packages, but did not work so I uninstalled them and I want to go back to the functionality of the application just through keyboard buttons but the animation of raising hand does not work anymore by pressing the space key. How should I fix it?

I have in the scene an EventSystem where appears that I should replace Standalone Input Module with InputSystemUIInputModule, should I replace it in order to work?

Comment: Please make the title more informative, i.e. `Input stopped working after installing XR packages`

Answer (score 0):

If you installed XR packages along with new Input System and before that you've used the old input system in your script (`Input.GetButton()` etc), it most likely that your project is now using only new input system, so there should be errors in console when your control script is running. Just find an option `Project Settings -> Player -> Active Input Handling` and set it to either `Input Manager (Old)` or `Both`, then your script should start working again.

Alternatively you can re-write your code to use New Input System following the examples - open `Window -> Package Manager`, find Input System and download samples, they will appear in your Project window.

Comment: it is already set to "Both" but the space key still does not work. what should I try?

Comment: Could you please add the code of your input to the question?

Answer (score 0):

In order for UnityEngine.UI interactables to work (such as UnityEngine.UI.Button), the hierarchy needs exactly one (don't create two or more!) of each of the following components:

- Event System
- UI input Module

They don't have to be on the same GameObject, but they need to be enabled and the GameObjects each belongs to need to be active in the Hierarchy.

There are two versions of the UI input module: one that belongs to the old package and one that belongs to their newest one.

You were likely using the old input package before, until you installed the XR package which only works with the newest input package - and it automatically updated your project replacing the old with the new.

However, in order to complete the upgrade you need to manually replace the Standalone Input Module (old) with the InputSystemUIInputModule (new).

It seems you did not replace that component, which could be the reason the XR package "didn't work".

After uninstalling the XR package, the new input system package remained so, in order to make your game work just as before, you need to do one of the following (but not both!):

1. Uninstall the new input package then go to Project Settings/Input to make sure the old one is set.
2. Replace the Input Module with their new one, you will also need to edit your code to use the new package and configure the package on it's input actions asset. I recommend checking their migration guide and documentation.

Personal opinion: Stick with the newest package, it's more flexible and powerful. The old package has also been deprecated the last few years and many recent packages require the new one to work.